Cannot get a value from a map with enum key
Write a code and find the get operation fails to obtain the value from a map with enum key.
For example, the checkers is initilized, then the get operations always return null. Why
class Test {
    static void main(String[] args){
        Map<CHANA_OPERATION, Closure> checkers = [VIDEO_GENERATION: (userId) -> {
            System.out.println("..............")
        }, TEXT_API_CALL: (userId)->{
            return false
        }]

        checkers.get(CHANA_OPERATION.VIDEO_GENERATION).call(1)
    }


    enum CHANA_OPERATION{
        VIDEO_GENERATION(0),
        TEXT_API_CALL(1),
        TEXT_VIDEO_API_CALL(2)

        int code
        CHANA_OPERATION(int code){
            this.code = code
        }
    }

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at com.chana.application.service.impl.Test.main(Test.groovy:11)



You are not actually using the enum here.  The map literal in Groovy
uses String keys and the quotes are optional (if the key can be parsed
as one token).
To use proper values for the keys, you have to put the value inside
parenthesis.  You also have to reference the enum-class.
E.g.
Map<CHANA_OPERATION, Closure> checkers = [
    (CHANA_OPERATION.VIDEO_GENERATION): { userId ->
//  X~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                X
        println "userId=$userId"
    }, //...
]


Your map has Strings as keys. Easy to check
println checkers.keySet()[0].class // class java.lang.String

You have two ways of fixing this:

The right way :) Declare your map with enums, not with Strings. Slightly more verbose, but your IDE can do SCA with all the benefits, like validation, autocompletion, etc.:

Map<CHANA_OPERATION, Closure> checkers1 = [
  (CHANA_OPERATION.VIDEO_GENERATION): { userId ->
    println("......VIDEO_GENERATION........")
  },
  (CHANA_OPERATION.TEXT_API_CALL): { userId ->
    println("......TEXT_API_CALL........")
  },
]


The wrong way. Cast enums to Strings at access time

checkers.get(CHANA_OPERATION.VIDEO_GENERATION.name()).call(1)

